# Integrate $ydx-xdy$ on ellipse

Tags: integration

$C = \{(x,y,z)|x^2+y^2=4,x+z=2\}$
How can i compute $\int_C y dx-x dy$? I can parametrize my ellipse, but it's terrible and i think that there is easier ways. But i don't know what ways.. 
And so what are general tricks for doing such calculations?
I tried use some relations like $dx+dz=0, xdx+ydy=0$, but with no benefits..

Comment: Do you know about [Green's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green's_theorem)?

Comment: Ok i tried it. So i obtain that i need to compute $\int_{C'} dx dy$(where C' is interior of my ellipse), but again i don't know how to do it. And i can't use Stoke's theorem for doing this task, but i also want to see how to calculate $\int_{C'} dx dy$

Comment: @RonGordon THX!

Comment: Adding as answer so the question can be closed out.

Comment: Don't we also need to know the orientation of the curve to get the sign right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like all you need to do is parametrize $x=2 \cos{t}$, $y=2 \sin{t}$.  The integral is independent of $z$, so $t \in [0,2 \pi]$ over $C$.  Thus the integral is $-8 \pi$ (given $C$ is positively oriented).

Comment: It's even easier to evaluate if you recognize the integrand: $\int_\Gamma \frac 1 2(x dy-y dx)$ is the (oriented) area swept out by the radius vector to the curve $\Gamma$, so, assuming that we trace the curve counterclockwise, we're looking for $-2$ times the area of a circle of radius 2.